# Is $\{A\in F^{n\times n}: Det(A)=0\}$ Subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

> Is $\{A\in F^{n\times n}: Det(A)=0\}$ a subgroup of $F^{n\times n} $?

When looking on both addition and multiplication the zero matrix is in $A$ and for all B,C both $det(B)+det(C)=0+0=0$ and $det(BC)=det(B)Det(C)=0\cdot 0=0$ so the operation is closed.

Now the last step is to show that it B in the group so does it inverse, so in the case of addition $e=0$ so we can find a matrix such that the adding it to an arbitrary matrix will give a determinant of $0$ and so for multiplication, but on the other hand a matrix has no inverse is $Det(B)=0$ So is there an inverse element or not?

Comment: what operation are you using in $F^{n\times n}$? That is the operation you should be using. $F^{n\times n}$ is a group with respect to addition, but ${\rm det}(B+C)\ne{\rm det}(B)+{\rm det}(C)$ (in fact your set is not generally closed under addition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a subgroup under multiplication. Matrices with determinant zero are not invertible; the inverse of a matrix A is defined to be
$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}\text{adj } A$$
If the determinant is zero, the inverse doesn't exist.

Comment: So it's a semigroup.

Comment: I doubt this is the expected answer, considering $F^{n \times n}$ *is* a group under some natural operation.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about concepts. Group needs only one operation with these specific properties, then you don't need verify mutiplication and sum.

And we can have $det(A+B) \neq det(A) + det(B)$.